# How do S3 file download and estimator.fit() work in this blog post?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

## Difficulty in understanding

Q2) How to download a file from S3?

**From**  [The Machine Learning Workflow with SageMaker](https://medium.com/akeneo-labs/machine-learning-workflow-with-sagemaker-b83b293337ff)

And also why are we using this piece of code?

`estimator.fit(train_data_location)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Downloading a file from S3:

This code block in the Q2 section defines the function that downloads a file from S3. The user instantiates an S3 client, and then passes the S3 URL along to the `s3.Bucket.download_file()` method.

```
def download_from_s3(url):
    """ex: url = s3://sagemakerbucketname/data/validation.tfrecords"""
    url_parts = url.split("/")  # => ['s3:', '', 'sagemakerbucketname', 'data', ...
    bucket_name = url_parts[2]
    key = os.path.join(*url_parts[3:])
    filename = url_parts[-1]
    if not os.path.exists(filename):
        try:
            # Create an S3 client
            s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
            print('Downloading {} to {}'.format(url, filename))
            s3.Bucket(bucket_name).download_file(key, filename)
        except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
            if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
                print('The object {} does not exist in bucket {}'.format(
                    key, bucket_name))
            else:
                raise
```

### Estimator.fit() explanation:

The `estimator.fit(train_data_location)` line is what initiates the training process with SageMaker. When run, SageMaker will provision the necessary infrastructure, fetch the data from the location the user designated (here, `train_data_location` which is a path to Amazon S3) and distribute it amongst the training cluster, carry out the training process, return the resulting model, and tear down the training infrastructure.

You can find the result of this training job in the SageMaker console.

Comment: Thanks that works well , Also for updating the question.